# Receive KeyError but key exists in nested dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, get

When trying to reference a value in my dictionary I receive KeyError, however the key (NIO) is in the dictionary.

Upon troubleshooting, I found that

```
['NIO']
<class 'str'>
```

creates the KeyError, but

```
NIO
<class 'str'>
```

runs the program as expected.

I don't fully understand the difference in the strings and have not been able to find a good explanation.

What is the difference in the strings above and how do I convert the first into the second?

Example below:

```
symbol = ['NIO']
holdings_data = {'BA': {'price': '122.720000', 'quantity': '1.00000000'}, 
'NIO': {'price': '2.440000', 'quantity': '2.00000000'}}


def trade_history(symbol, holdings_data):
    symbol = str(symbol)
    print(symbol)
    print(type(symbol))
    #symbol = 'NIO'
    #print(symbol)
    #print(type(symbol))
    quantity = (holdings_data[symbol].get('quantity'))
    print(quantity)

trade_history(symbol, holdings_data)
```

returns

```
KeyError: "['NIO']"
```

but adding in

```
symbol = 'NIO'
print(symbol)
print(type(symbol))
```

returns

```
['NIO']
<class 'str'>
NIO
<class 'str'>
2.00000000
```

Comment: Can you make an example that people can run and reproduce the actual error.

Comment: In the first example, it looks like a one-item list ['NIO']. In the second example, without quotation marks, NIO is a variable. Hard to know what is really happening without more details.

Comment: Probably the problem is that NIO is a string 'abc' and he is trying to use the string 'NIO' to access the dictionary but we can be sure without the example @EricTruett

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have added the example code  @BrunoMello

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have added the example code @MarkMeyer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have added the example code @EricTruett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
symbol = str(symbol)
```

It should be:

```
symbol = str(symbol[0])
```

This happens because you are trying to change a list to a string

Comment: thanks! That gets it to work, but for the future... what is the difference in the two strings?

Comment: When you do the first, it puts the [] in the string because it is a list and thus the final string will be ['NIO'] instead of NIO